# I can't post my file on the server with formData from the state

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, axios, vuex

I'm not able to post a form data on my server files as formData from my store.
Checking the state before submit I can see that image and video properties have formDatas as values, but on submit the params of the request are empty object

```
<template>
    <input type="file" @change="onImageSelected($event)" accept="image/*" >
</template>
```

---

```
methods: {
            submit() {
                this.$v.$touch()
                if (this.$v.$invalid || this.tags.length > 3) {
                    this.submitStatus = 'ERROR'
                } else {
                    this.submitStatus = 'PENDING'
                    this.$store.dispatch('exercises/storeExercise')

                }
            },
            onImageSelected(event) {
                this.image = event.target.files[0]
                if (this.image.size < 8000000) {
                    const formDataImage = new FormData()
                    formDataImage.append('image', this.image)
                    this.$store.dispatch('exercises/commitImageSelected', formDataImage)
                }
            },
}
```

---

```
const state = {
    exercises: [],
    tags: [],
    selectedExercise: null,
    selectedComponent: BeforeSelect
    }

const mutations = {
    setImageSelected(state, image) {
        Vue.set(state.selectedExercise, 'image', image)
    },
    setVideoSelected(state, video) {
        Vue.set(state.selectedExercise, 'video', video)
    }
}

const actions = {
        commitImageSelected({commit}, image){
            commit('setImageSelected', image)
        },
        commitVideoSelected({commit}, video){
            commit('setVideoSelected', video)
        },
        storeExercise({commit, state}) {
            axios.post('exercises', state.selectedExercise)
                .then(({data}) => {
                    commit('setExercises', data)
                    })
                    .catch(err => console.log(err))
        },
```

}

Comment: Does the form have a 'delay' after submitting a bigger file?
If not - that could imply that file isn't even being sent, in which case you have to wrap the input inside a form with enctype set to 'multipart/form-data'.

Answer (score 0):

Try this axios post in storeExcerise method.

```
axios.post('exercises',state.selectedExercise,{
          headers: { 'Content-Type': undefined},
        }).then(function (response) {
          if (response.data.ok) {
          }
        }.bind(this));
```

This is working fine for me while uploading file to server.